# In Terraform, how to pass variables to powershell template file?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I am creating a windows EC2 instance using Terraform. I am setting powershell script to user_data that will run after the instance is launched.

```
resource "aws_instance" "windows_runner" {
  ami                  = var.ami_id
  instance_type        = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.runner_instance.name
  key_name             = var.key_name
  security_groups      = [aws_security_group.windows.id]
  subnet_id            = data.aws_subnet.work.id
  tags                 = var.tags
  user_data            = teamplatefile("userdata.tftpl",
                        {
                          environment_name = var.environment_name,
                          instance_type = var.instance_type
                        })
}
```

So I am passing these two variables to `templatefile` function, and I want to consume those two variables in powershell script. Based on the [documentation][1]

> The "vars" argument must be a map. Within the template file, each of
> the keys in the map is available as a variable for interpolation

Here is how userdata.tftpl will consume those variables

```
<powershell>
Set-Location -Path "C:\GitLab-Runner"
$token = "sometoken"
$url = "https://gitlab-instance.domain.com/"
$runner_name = "windows-runner-$instance_type"
$executor = "shell"
$shell = "powershell"
$builds_location = "c:\builds"
$tags = "$environment_name-windows-$instance_type"


New-Item -Path $builds_location -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "$builds_location has been created!"


# register runner. Trailing backtick to span on multiple line. White space matters
.\gitlab-runner.exe register `
--non-interactive `
--url $url `
--registration-token $token `
--name $runner_name `
--executor $executor `
--shell $shell `
--builds-dir $builds_location `
--tag-list $tags `
--locked="false"


.\gitlab-runner.exe install    

.\gitlab-runner.exe start    

</powershell>
```

Questions
1> How these variables will be available in powershell?
2> Can I simply use `$environment_name` and `$instance_type` in PS script?
3> or will these variables passed as parameters to the PS script? In this case do I need to define and match the parameter names or order?
4>Will the PS script execute in Adminstyrator mode on launched instance?

**Bonus**
I found examples using templatefile on linux and shell script. Not finding a good example with windows and powershell
[1]: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile

Comment: You need `$builds_location = c:\builds\${environment_name}\${instance_type}` at a first glance.